# Finding the maximum storage of a CD from measurements of pits and lands?

Tags: data, optics, data-storage

Full disclosure: This is schoolwork. I'm not asking for anyone to solve this for me, I am only asking if I'm on the right track with my thinking.

I have imagery of a CD from an atomic force microscope showing the pits and lands. Using [Gwyddion](http://gwyddion.net) I have measured the lengths of 150 different pits.

The task I am currently stuck on is finding the maximum amount of data the disc can hold. My thinking is that if the minimum size of a pit is 3 channel bit periods, this represents 2 bits of data. I could use my measurements of the smallest pits to find the area per unit bit, then use the area of the writeable surface of the CD to find the total amount of bits a CD can hold.

My issue with this is that the AFM imagery is not perfect, and area calculations of the pits and lands may be rough. Is there a better way of doing this or am I on the right track with my thinking?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is looking up the manufacturer's specification of the CD an option?  At the very least knowing the specification could let you verify what you are finding by counting the pits and lands.

In general I would think that the spacing between each spiral pattern on the disk would be a standard, (equal to the resolution of the reader optics), so the total length of a full track rather then the disk's area should be the limiting factor.

Comment: Oh right, using the pitch and radius of the spiral would likely be much more accurate than the area. Also I do have the manufacturer's specs, I just can't find the actual value since I'm on mobile. Thanks for your help!